# Significance of Cyrillic text in Sapper Morton's farm

Tags: analysis, reference, blade-runner-2049

At the beginning of Blade Runner 2049, when K visits Sapper Morton's farm, there is a shot that shows what looks like a greenhouse with Cyrillic characters on it.

[image]

From what I understand, that word reads `tsielina`, which means "[new soil](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)" (and sounds a lot like dr. Stelline's name, but that may be a coincidence). Is there a particular significance to this word?

Comment: Could be related to this question: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/81423/why-are-english-russian-japanese-cultures-emphasized-in-the-blade-runner-2049

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/172806/769

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, "new soil" is almost **not** correct.

I'll refer to a good [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgin_Lands_Campaign) about it  instead of trying to explain it myself.

> The **Virgin Lands** Campaign was Nikita Khrushchev’s 1953 plan to dramatically boost the Soviet Union’s agricultural production in order to alleviate the food shortages plaguing the Soviet populace.

Comment: This answer provides a translation, but doesn't answer the question asked. Is there any *significance* to it.

Comment: The world in which Blade Runner is set has seen an apocalyptic event decimate a huge part of Earth's human and animal population, and leaving the globe largely contaminated, to the point that any kind of non-artificial pet is a good of extreme luxury. I find it quiet easy to draw a parallel between this context of scarcity and the food shortages mentioned in the article.

Answer (score 3):

The word `tselina` (no soft consonants as normal) means "celery" in Bulgarian. You don't need to look for metaphorical connections in other languages: given that we see this written on a greenhouse, it's pretty safe to assume that the only significance it has is to denote what's growing in there.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds anticlimatic compared to the other answer, but nevertheless it makes a lot of sense given the context. If I understand correctly the Russian and Bulgarian word are written in the exact same way, so it seems impossible to tell which is the correct interpretation without external clues.

Comment: Except that it's clear from the movie and the internet shorts that he grows some sort of insect based protein.  Given the apparent ecological collapse, i find the 'metaphorical connection' in Russian much more compelling an answer.